# gdalwarp leaves horizontal artifacts regridding from EASE-Grid (laea) to Polarstero (stere)

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I'm trying to understand how to use gdalwarp to warp an image.  I believe I'm doing the basics correctly, but I might be missing some gdalwarp options.

The basic problem is that I see horizontal artifiacts in my output image.

Here's basic steps to reproduce.

Start with a simple 722x722 image.  [Here's one on imagur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeC8T.jpg) [(Direct link to png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeC8T.jpg.png)

Now use gdal_translate to apply metadata to make this a geotiff (this is a EASE-grid Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection on a 1924 authallic sphere.)

```
gdal_translate -a_srs '+proj=laea +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371228 +b=6371228 +units=m +no_defs' \
    -a_ullr -4524688.262500000 4524688.262500000 4524688.262500000 -4524688.262500000  \
    -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 -co ZLEVEL=9 \
    -of GTiff ./UiMbqSd.png ./UiMbqSd.withmetadata.tif
```

This seems to have the expected geographic information (~12.5km grid) confirmed with gdalinfo

```
 gdalinfo UiMBqSd.withmetadata.tif


Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: UiMbqSd.withmetadata.tif
Size is 722, 722
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unnamed ellipse",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["unnamed",6371228,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",90],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-4524688.262500000186265,4524688.262500000186265)
Pixel Size = (12533.762500000000728,-12533.762500000000728)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-4524688.263, 4524688.263) (135d 0' 0.00"W, 29d42'45.71"N)
Lower Left  (-4524688.263,-4524688.263) ( 45d 0' 0.00"W, 29d42'45.71"N)
Upper Right ( 4524688.263, 4524688.263) (135d 0' 0.00"E, 29d42'45.71"N)
Lower Right ( 4524688.263,-4524688.263) ( 45d 0' 0.00"E, 29d42'45.71"N)
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=722x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=722x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=722x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=722x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

Next I regrid it to a polarstero projection.

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=-45 +lat_ts=70 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m" \
    ./UiMbqSd.withmetadata.tif ./regridded_lon0_-45.tif
```

The problem I'm seeing is horizontal artifacts that appear to protrude around the middle of the image.
Here's the png representation of the problem (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWaUy.jpg)

I thought it might be something weird about my corners, but I see these artifacts with different lat_0 values.

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=70 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m" \
    ./UiMbqSd.withmetadata.tif ./regridded_lon0_0.tif
```

Here's an example with no rotation (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTos0.jpg)

I'm currently running this on a mac:

```
> gdalwarp --version
GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24
```

But I've tested and seen the same behavior on UBUNTU 12.04:

```
GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26
```

Comment: Great examples and test image. It was simple to repeat the test. I got similar results with GDAL 2.0-dev on Windows. If you won't get an answer from here you can try gdal-dev mailing list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the -et (error threshold) option with lower thresholds than the default (0.125). When I use "-et 0.01", the horizontal artifacts disappear:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=-45 +lat_ts=70 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m" \
    -et 0.01 \
    ./UiMbqSd.withmetadata.tif ./regridded_lon0_-45.tif
```

Comment: I'm using `gdal_translate` and have the same issue, but there seems to be on `-et` option for gdal_translate. Any suggestions on what to do there? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the resampling method for gdalwarp, e.g.

```
gdalwarp -r mode etc. etc.
```

which seems to remove your problem. What makes most sense will be different for different data.

Comment: I just tried this with: 

`gdalwarp -r {TYPE} -t_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=70 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m" ./UiMbqSd.withmetadata.tif ./regridded_{TYPE}.tif`

Where `TYPE = [average, lanczos, cubicspline, cubic, mode, bilinear, near]`

All of them continue to show the artifacts.  

For the record, the actual data I'm trying to regrid is ice age data, so it's coded integers and I need to keep the values from the input grid.

Thanks
Matt