# GDAL VRT - gap artifact in output

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalbuildvrt

I have created a [VRT](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html) using `gdalbuildvrt` from three single-band GeoTiffs (1-m resolution) as follows:

```
gdalbuildvrt chm_2157.vrt P_712806_CHM.tif P_712808_CHM.tif P_712810_CHM.tif  -a_srs 'epsg:2157' -srcnodata 1.175494351e-38
```

When I checked the output in QGIS, I noticed that a gap of 1 pixel (1-m) has appeared between two of the input tiles. Below are pictures of the input tiles (no gap present) and the VRT output (gap artifact included)

**Input GeoTiff (no gap)**
[image]

**Output VRT (gap)**
[image]

I've read threads about this issue occurring with `gdalwarp` and `gdal_merge.py` (e.g. [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116465/gdalwarp-leaves-horizontal-artifacts-regridding-from-ease-grid-laea-to-polarst) ) but the solutions don't appear to apply to `gdalbuildvrt`.

Comment: Download links to small images which could be used for reproducing the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: I've noticed that the gap disappears, when I save the input GeoTiffs from QGIS using the 'Save As' option and then create the VRT. Here is a link to the two input files. http://jmp.sh/b/6pGVpiCBt5Mxqp99HEGo