# gdal warp reproject creates artifact in raster

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp

I’m trying to re-project a tif-file using gdal warp:

```
fn = "\dtm.tif"
out = "\dtm_25832.tif"
gdal.Warp(out, fn, dstSRS="EPSG:25832")
```

The output file is re-projected, but it creates artifacts in the output file.

Is there a way to avoid creating artifacts?

Artifacts are more visible on hillshade-dem.

[image]

```
from osgeo import gdal
import os
fn = 'DEM.tif'

# open dataset
rds = gdal.Open(fn)
ds = gdal.Open(fn)
ds.GetMetadata()
{'AREA_OR_POINT': 'Area',
'TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT': '2 (pixels/inch)',
'TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION': '72',
'TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION': '72'}
rds.GetDescription()
'C:\\Python\\Test\\DEM.tif'
img_width,img_height=rds.RasterXSize,rds.RasterYSize
img_width,img_height
(15010, 30010)
ds.GetGeoTransform()
(-39575.0, 1.0, 0.0, 6726005.0, 0.0, -1.0)
ds.GetProjection()
```

> PROJCS["ETRS89 / UTM zone
> 33N",GEOGCS["ETRS89",DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",SPHEROID["GRS
> 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",15],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","25833"]]

Comment: Please include `gdalinfo` report and screenshot of input dtm.tif.

Comment: Try some other resampling than "nearest" that is the default.

Comment: I have tried with different resampling methods - still the same problem.

Comment: Small sample of data and exact parameters would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the input coordinate reference system? Or just edit the question with the gdalinfo report please.

Comment: Here is another [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116465/gdalwarp-leaves-horizontal-artifacts-regridding-from-ease-grid-laea-to-polarst) that could provide useful.

Comment: It is a DEM your reprojecting right, and not a hillshade like the one in your screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed a very similar issue when reprojecting both LiDAR and 10 meter DEM data with ArcGIS Project Raster Tool. Visible below in a slope raster. I suspect it is a side-effect of the fact that projecting a raster is not as clean an operation as projecting a vector. Interestingly this did affect my slope calculation for this watershed by from 11.6% original to 12.9% after projection. The jaggedness seems to have translated to a steeper mean slope calculation.

Original GCS (NAD1983)
[image: Original GCS (NAD1983)]

New PCS(NAD1983 Stateplane)
[image: New PCS(NAD1983 Stateplane)]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the error threshold (-et) option to something lower than the default ([like here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116465/gdalwarp-leaves-horizontal-artifacts-regridding-from-ease-grid-laea-to-polarst)).